# password_verify() not verifying hashed password

Tags: php, hash

I'm trying to has a password in PHP using `password_hash` and `password_verify`. I am correctly hashing the password as it is being into the database hashed, but when I attempt to unhash the password whilst logging in, it doesn't seem to want to work. The password is being recieved from an Android application but after echoing both the username and the password, they are correct to what they should be. To hash the password, I am using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` as the hashing technique.

Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once('dbconnect.php');

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username ='$username'");

        if(empty($result)){
            die("Username doesn't exist");
        }   

    $dbpass = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM User WHERE username = '$username'");

    if (password_verify($password, $dbpass)){

        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

        $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, $stmt));

        if(isset($check)){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "password not unhashing";
    }

$conn->close();
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `$dbpass` isn't the password, it's the result set from the query; you're going to need to fetch the individual row and then access the password entry from that row..... PHP databases 101

Comment: You also seem to be playing pick-a-mix with procedural and object styles of database access

Comment: $dbpass = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM User WHERE username = '$username'");

if (password_verify($password, $dbpass)){  --- you need to fetch password from dbPass

Comment: god damn, thanks guys i realise why i was being dumb now.

Comment: I'll set my username to `'; drop table users; --'` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use prepared statements to remove the threat of SQL injection, or your login screen becomes an attack vector.  Then the problem is you're not getting the actual dbpass, you're getting a result set containing $dbpass, without dereferencing it.

Try it this way:

```
//username in where clause is coming from the user, don't execute it
//also fetch a clean copy of the username from the database we can trust to do things with like display -- assuming we filtered it on the way into the database.    
$stmnt = $conn->prepare('select username,password from user where username = ?') or die('...');


//username must be a string, and to keep it clear it came from a user, and we don't trust it, leave it in POST.
$stmnt->bind_param('s',$_POST['username']) or die('...');


//Do the query.
$stmnt->execute() or die('...');

//Where to put the results.
$stmnt->bind_result($username,$dbpass);

//Fetch the results
if($stmnt->fetch()) //get the result of the query.
{
  if(password_verify($_POST['password'],$dbpass))
  {
    //The password matches.
  }
  else
  {
    //password doesn't match.
  }
}
else
{
  //username is wrong.
}
```